# =IFERROR(IF(MIN(Milestones[Start])=0,TODAY(),MIN(Milestones[Start])),TODAY()), throws error in the range Milestones[Start]

Tags: excel

=IFERROR(IF(MIN(Milestones[Start])=0,TODAY(),MIN(Milestones[Start])),TODAY()), throws error at Milestones[Start]

It must actually return the minimum date within a named range, I have named ranges Milestones and Start.

Comment: Is your named range `Milestones` a table and the column in it is `Start`? We'll need way more detail but I can easily write this formula for you. I just need the info.

Comment: Yes, it is in table form and [Start] is a column in the table [Milestones]

Comment: Found my mistake thank you, it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the formula to work exactly as you have it written, the "named range" must be a table format. The table is labelled `Milestones`, in that table the column must be labelled `Start` and in that it should have the dates as date format (it's more important it's actually numbers than how it's formatted).

`=IFERROR(IF(MIN(Milestones[Start])=0,TODAY(),MIN(Milestones[Start])),TODAY())`

Depending what you're calling a "Named Range" your solution can be one of these.

`=IFERROR(IF(MIN(Milestones)=0,TODAY(),MIN(Milestones)),TODAY())`

`=IFERROR(IF(MIN(Start)=0,TODAY(),MIN(Milestones[Start])),TODAY())`